# Slow responsetime from Amazon Ec2 instance

Tags: java, http, amazon-ec2, tomcat8, okhttp

Im running Java/Spring application with a Angular6 frontend. Within the Spring backend I calling another API thru http. but its around 6x slower than expected to get at response...

Isolating the API-call I get:

Locally running the same setup (Spring, Tomcat 8.5) from my dev-machine: 10-12 sec
Locally thru Postman: 10-12 sec
locally thru cUrl: 10-12 sec
Using cUrl from the console on the AWS EC2 instance 10-12sec.

Calling as intended (Spring running in Tomcat) on the AWS EC2 instance: 60-75sec.

Tried to change the Native Spring http (ResponseEntity postForEntity) call to OkHttp with no change in the result. The Api request and response is a tiny Json-string but the APi is slow so response times around 10 sec is normal.

As it seems to be something wrong with the Tomcat or java on the EC2.  Can it be some parameters that I missed? or what else can i try to isolate and solve the problem?

The amount of data sent and revived is trivial (sending ~350 bytes, receiving less than that)

Its just the call to the API that takes a long time.

```
logger.debug("CallApi start");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(apiCalcDTO.getInput());

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();


            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, body);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://www.example.com/api/1.0/xxx")
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            logger.debug("CallApi time = " + elapsed);
```

Comment: Did you check where exactly the slow response time is occurring e.g. sending request, business logic, DB calls, creating response? Are you for example sending a large request body (which would take time to send)? Are there other AWS services involved in your stack outside of what you've mentioned above?

Comment: Could not respond in comment so I edited the question with the info you ask about.

Comment: any update on the issue? @Tillmark.. im facing similar issue.